# Amplab shark with HBase

Tags: hbase, bigdata, shark-sql

What is a good way to set up access to a HBase table through shark queries? I explored some articles which are geared towards setting up HBase with Hive such as https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration , but not too sure how this applies for Shark. I am mainly looking for read's from HBase through Shark. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Shark is no longer supported I guess, why not try spark-sql instead?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables could help when you use spark-sql with hive. i.e. you create hive table that use hbaseStoragehandler using `hql(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING)) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz"))` and query it as `hql("FROM src SELECT key, value").collect().foreach(println)`

Comment: Btw, I haven't try this myself but it sounds possible. :),  since for Hive, HBase is just another data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in the question worked as is with shark acting as a drop in replacement for hive.